# How to convert list to dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 50 columns in that 25 columns are of type list. How can I convert them to final single dataframe with type as integer

I am doing it with

```
df_list=names(which(sapply(df,is.list))
df_list=df[df_list]
do.call("rbind",df_list)
```

But it does not do the conversion. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the `list` columns by looping over the columns specified by 'df_list' and assign the output back

```
df[df_list] <- lapply(df[df_list], unlist)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = I(as.list(1:5)), col3 = I(as.list(6:10)))
df_list <- sapply(df, is.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

### convert list to dataframe

```
df_list=df[df_list]
library(data.table)
rbindlist(df_list, idcol=TRUE)
```